# How do I clean up form using recompose in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, recompose

After form submit I want to clean it but this solution doesn't seem to work. here's my submit handler:

```
handleSubmit: ({ title, body }, props) => e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    props
        .handleCreatePost({
            variables: {
                title,
                body
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            return {
                title: "",
                body: ""
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you need to change props from inside of your component you have to use `withStateHandlers`.

```
compose(
  withStateHandlers(
    ({title, body})=> ({title, body}), //set the state from parent props
    { 
      setTitle: () => title => ({title}), // update the title
      setBody: () => body => ({body}), // update the body
      clearProps: () => () => ({titel:'', body: ''}) // create a handler to reset the values
    }
  ),
  withHandlers({
    handleSubmit: ({ title, body, clearProps }, props) => e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      props
        .handleCreatePost({
          variables: {
            title,
            body
          }
        })
        .then(clearProps) // reset the values 
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
      }
    )
)
```